# Using crawler4j. How can i save website data?

Tags: web-crawler

I have started using crawler4j and it seems to be looking up websites with no issues. Yet, I need to save the crawled data. Does crawler4j support this functionality?

I have tried using the advanced java source code (and Downloader.java) but it doesn't seem to be working

Specifically the code below never prints anything.

```
    Downloader myDownloader = new Downloader();
    Page page = myDownloader.download("http://ics.uci.edu");

    if (page != null) {
        System.out.println(page.getText());
    }
```

I would appreciate some input on this

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you're rolling your own Crawler that extends the WebCrawler class you have access to the details of the page that was crawled in the Visit(Page) method.  For example the following will get you the contents of the page:

```
String content = new String(page.getContentData(), page.getContentCharset());
```

From there you can save it to disk or apply any processing that's required.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it with other pages? In fact, the url you're using is missing a "www". The correct one is http://www.ics.uci.edu/